# Batch updating point attributes based on values of underlying polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, select-by-location, intersect

I have a points shapefile with a blank field. I want to populate this field with an attribute obtained from another underlying (polygon) shapefile. I can do this for a single record easily using select by location - in other words point y is located in area x, so the field updates itself with area x. The problem is that my shapefile has nearly half a million records and I need to do this often. I have no scripting experience at all.

Is there a simple batch method that will do this job?

Answer (score 5):

The [Intersect (Analysis)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool should be able to do the point-in-polygon overlay that you are after quite quickly.

I would recommend having both shapefiles on your local disk (or copying them into an in_memory workspace) for best performance.